# use YCSB test cassandra ,the performance not so good

Tags: cassandra, ycsb

All:
my enviroment as follows:
3* nodes (64*Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 CPU @ 2.30GHz , memory :256G, 2 x 3.2TB direct attached NVMe SSD)
Cassandra 3.11.10 (Default configuration parameters were used)
YCSB : 0.17.0
Replication factor = 3

test result, use 30, 64,128 and so on threads , the bigest ops/sec only 32k.

Could you please give me some advices? how to improve the performance?

Thanks,
Regards
Spring

Comment: YCSB isn't very representative - try NoSQLBench: http://docs.nosqlbench.io/#/. Plus many things are dependent on the data model & node configuration, such as, heap size what garbage collector is used, etc.

Comment: but i really want to use YCSB.

Comment: 32k ops/sec with RF=3 on 3 nodes seems pretty fast to me.  If that's not enough, add more nodes.

Comment: Also, did you use the "default configuration" for garbage collection, too?  Might want to adjust that, because it'll cap itself at 8GB for heap size.  Why provision an instance w/ 256GB RAM if you're not going to use it, right?

Comment: yes, the gc also use the "default configuration" .ok , I will try